# Is there a way to keep execCommand("insertHTML") from removing attributes in chrome?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

Context is Chrome 37.0.2062.120 m.

I'm using execCommand to insert html into an editable div.  My execCommand call looks like this:

```
function insertHTML(){
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '<span id="myId">hi</span>');
}
```

When the editable div looks like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    some [insertion point] content
</div>
```

and I use execCommand to insert html into a contenteditable div, all of the attributes of the HTML are inserted as expected and I end up with this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    some <span id="myId">hi</span> content
</div>
```

When, however, I insert the exact same html into this structure:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    some content
    <div>more [insertion point] content</div>
</div>
```

The attributes are removed from the span being inserted and it ends up looking like this:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    some content
    <div>more <span style="font-size: 10pt;">hi</span> content</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to keep this from happening?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In this particular case I would suggest using [`Range.insertNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.insertNode) instead, which will give you total control of what gets inserted:

```
function insertHTML() {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).rangeCount) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.collapse(true);
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.id = "myId";
        span.appendChild( document.createTextNode("hi") );
        range.insertNode(span);

        // Move the caret immediately after the inserted span
        range.setStartAfter(span);
        range.collapse(true);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    }
}
```

```js
function isOrIsAncestorOf(ancestor, descendant) {
  var n = descendant;
  while (n) {
    if (n === ancestor) {
      return true;
    } else {
      n = n.parentNode;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function nodeContainsSelection(node) {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).rangeCount) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    return isOrIsAncestorOf(node, range.commonAncestorContainer);
  }
  return false;
}

function insertHTML() {
  var sel, range;
  if (window.getSelection && (sel = window.getSelection()).rangeCount) {
    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    range.collapse(true);
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.id = "myId";
    span.appendChild( document.createTextNode("hi") );
    range.insertNode(span);

    // Move the caret immediately after the inserted span
    range.setStartAfter(span);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("inserter").onmousedown = function() {
    var editor = document.getElementById("editor");
    if (nodeContainsSelection(editor)) {
      insertHTML();
      return false;
    }
  };
};
```

```css
span {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="inserter" value="Insert span">
<div contenteditable="true" id="editor">
    some content
</div>
```

Comment: This is a great alternative, thank you so much.  I noticed in the snippet that I could add a span next to the button as well as in the editable div if the selection wasn't in the div.  Is there a way to constrain that?

Comment: @sonicblis: Yes: you can check whether the `commonAncestorContainer` property of the selection range is contained within the editable div. I've added example code to the snippet.

Comment: Note: In constrast to execCommand, this will not modify the browser's undo stack. This means that you cannot undo the insertion in a content editable element using Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Another approach to preserve undo stack use is to simply add/modify the attribute manually, through separate JS to do so, after inserting.  The attribute modification itself will be outside the browser's undo stack but the insertion of the rest of the HTML is within the control of the undo/redo stack.

Comment: Bro, thank you so much for that hint! I've been trying to find this solution for hours!

Comment: This example sadly does not preserve the undo history for the contenteditable area (so undo is never possible).

Comment: @SuperNova: That's true. I've written [another answer on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8544210/96100), although it's out of date: the UndoManager spec seems to be abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

One solution might be to not use span, i.e. use a non-span element. I have used the element `<em>` instead, to solve a similar problem with Chrome, because italics is fine by me - and as a consequence the `<span>`-fiddling "bug" in Chrome does not affect me. See discussion here: [Discussion re CKEdit bug, but relevant here too](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9004)