# How can i remove the span which created by method document.execCommand()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

the HTML code is

```
<p contentEditable="true" onmouseup="setColor();">this is some text</p>
```

and javascript code is

```
document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, true);
document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)")
```

;
so the DOM tree becomes：

```
<p contenteditable="true" onmouseup="setColor();">
    this is <span style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.498039);">some</span> text
</p>
```

Noticed that it inserts a span label,with the style attribute,the word's color changed.
Now what should i do ,when i want remove the span label?So that the word's color will turn default back.i've tried

```
document.execCommand('foreColor', false, "");
```

but it doen't work.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941559/is-there-a-way-to-keep-execcommandinserthtml-from-removing-attributes-in-chr