# How to remove the styles which are applied using document.execCommand in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to apply super script and sub script styles to the selected text in contenteditable div.
Please check the below which I am using now (I am able to apply the styles but if I type new characters it is showing in old style either in superscript or subscript)

component.html

```html
     <div style="display: flex;">
        <!-- "role!=='Admin'? 'finalize-editor':'admin-editor'"" -->
        <button  type="button" class="btn spe-btn" (click)="isSupScript = !isSupScript; setStyle('superScript')" matTooltip="Super Script">
            X<sup>2</sup>
        </button>
        <button  style="margin-left: 20px;" type="button" class="btn spe-btn" (click)="isSubScript= !isSubScript; setStyle('subScript')" matTooltip="Sub Script">
            X<sub>2</sub>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="delete-dialog" style="padding: 10px;">
    <div class="editor" #editor [(innerHtml)]="description" (input)="onChange()" contenteditable></div>
    <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="isShow">{{errorMsg}}</span>
</div>
```

component.ts

```typescript
  setStyle(style: string) {
    let bool = document.execCommand(style, false, '');
  }
```

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941559/is-there-a-way-to-keep-execcommandinserthtml-from-removing-attributes-in-chr

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking, or what the current behavior is. It would be better if you could provide a [mre]. But if you're saying that clicking the superscript button causes all text typed after pressing it to be superscript then that is what is supposed to happen, if I'm not mistaken. Of course, `execCommand` is not part of any standard, and it is not expected to be part of any standard, so you're at risk of it suddenly not working any time a browser maker decides to...